# Issue formatting a list of dictionaries to be used by javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I'm fairly new to Django, and I'm looking for the ideal way to handle data queried from GraphQL and creating HTML elements from the data to display on my website.

I've been generating a list of dictionaries from product information, all of which have "id", "name", "price", etc. and passing them onto my template as is.

On the template I can traverse the list with a for loop and the items correctly display within a p element as {'id': '...', 'title': '...' } However on js what I see is a string containing [{'id':... What's the ideal way to generate a list of dictionaries usable by JS from this string?

Also, declaring a variable with the filter |safe as such:
var products = "{{data|safe}}";
generates an Unexpected Identifier error for some reason.

Comment: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into using the `json_script` template tag:

```
{{ value|json_script:"json-data" }}
```

This will render into a tag like so:

```
<script id="json-data" type="application/json">{"key": "value"}</script>
```

You can use it in javascript by writing:

```
const value = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('json-data').textContent);
```

Reference: [Django docs- json_script](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script)

Another option would be to return a JsonResponse for an ajax request made using javascript.